# Part of value inside of 'style' attrs to become variable in python bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attrs.xml

Let's assume we have code:

```
 <tr class=" " somethingc1="" somethingc2="" somethingc3="" data-something="1" something="1something4" something_id="6something7">
 <td class="text-center td_something">
 <div>
 <span doo="true" class="foo" style="left:70%;z-index:99;">
 <span doo="true" class="foo" style="left:50%;z-index:90;">
 <span doo="true" class="Kung foo" style="left:90%;z-index:95;">
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class=" " somethingc1="" somethingc2="" somethingc3="" data-something="1" something="1something4" something_id="6something7">
 <td class="text-center td_something">
 <div>
 <span doo="true" class="Kung foo" style="left:35%;z-index:95;">
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class=" " somethingc1="" somethingc2="" somethingc3="" data-something="1" something="1something4" something_id="6something7">
 <td class="text-center td_something">
 <div>
 <span doo="true" class="foo" style="left:99%;z-index:100;">
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

How may I make a list using Bs4 in Python to find the highest value of 'left' in 'style' attrs keeping in mind that I do not want to take into consideration spans with class_ "Kung"

Desired result would be:

```
[70,False or NaN,99]
```

I've got it I should start with something like:

```
trs = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={"data-something": "1"})
List = list()
find_all('span',{'style': re.compile(r'^left:.')})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import bs4
>>> HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
```

First, select all of the element whose `class` contains `foo` (whether or not it contains something else as well).

```
>>> elements = soup.select('.foo')
```

In each case `element['class']` will be a list of the items in `class` for the element, ie, either just `foo` or `foo` and `Kung` in the case of this HTML. Thus a test for the length of `element['class']` is a test for the presence of `foo` alone.

`element['style']` gets the contents of `style` for the element. Use a regex for the part of it we want, and add it to the list called `lefts`.

```
>>> lefts = [ ]
>>> for element in elements:
...     if len(element['class'])==1:
...         lefts.append(int(bs4.re.search(r'left:([0-9]+)', element['style']).groups(0)[0]))
... 
>>> 
>>> lefts
[70, 50, 99]
```

**Edit:**

Find the `tr` elements, then look for the `elements` with class `foo`. As before, include consideration of only those elements with just class `foo` not both `foo` and `Kung`. Gather `left` style elements for these elements and then find the maximum values of them.

```
>>> HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> trs = soup.findAll('tr')
>>> tr_max = []
>>> for tr in trs:
...     elements = tr.select('.foo')
...     lefts = [ ]
...     for element in elements:
...         if len(element['class'])==1:
...             lefts.append(int(bs4.re.search(r'left:([0-9]+)', element['style']).groups(0)[0]))
...     if lefts:
...         tr_max.append(max(lefts))
...     else:
...         tr_max.append(None)
... 
>>> tr_max
[70, None, 99]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Not exactly, what I've looked for, but gives huge push into correct direction!

Comment: My pleasure. I was puzzled by  how you would get `[70,False or NaN,99]` from that HTML.

Comment: It is about separating the 'left' value for each 'tr' and look for max in it, so if in the first one has two 'lefts' it should bring higher. Second has no valid left, so False (or NaN if result must be integer), third would be 99. This is the issue I try to solve yet. Max value is probably easy for each element of array, but diversing them with 'tr' is harder.

Comment: Some kind of .parent comparator maybe would be a solution.

Comment: Marvelous! It was the part I was not able to handle ;) Thank you again!

Comment: Oh actually I just tried to upvote it, however I am too newbie to rate others' answers. Already done I guess.

Comment: No worries. I do appreciate having my answers accepted.